# Web Service Error "There was no endpoint listening at..." Firewall Concern

Tags: asp.net, web-services, firewall

So I have a web service service reference that works localhost and can be pinged from its production url but I can't get access to it via the Service Reference call in production. I believe the issue is my firewall . I have two websites on the same server each with their own dedicated IP address. I am trying to call the web service on the second website from the first website. If I open a browser on my production server I cannot navigate to either website.

Error Description:There was no endpoint listening at http://[209.112.245.103]/Services/OfferService.asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Inner Exception:Unable to connect to the remote server

The calling website is on the same server (different IP of course) and is calling the web service via a service reference:

```
 Dim offerService As New ServiceReferenceOffer.OfferServiceSoapClient("OfferServiceSoap")

offerService.BroadcastOfferChange(offer.PropertyID, offer.OfferID, offer.ResultResponse)
```

And my web.config contains the following service endpoint information:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="OfferServiceSoap" />
                <binding name="ConversationServiceSoap" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="OfferServiceSoap12">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                    <httpTransport />
                </binding>
                <binding name="ConversationServiceSoap12">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                    <httpTransport />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://209.112.245.103/Services/ConversationService.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ConversationServiceSoap"
                contract="ServiceReferenceConversation.ConversationServiceSoap"
                name="ConversationServiceSoap" />
            <endpoint address="http://209.112.245.103/Services/ConversationService.asmx"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ConversationServiceSoap12"
                contract="ServiceReferenceConversation.ConversationServiceSoap"
                name="ConversationServiceSoap12" />
            <endpoint address="http://209.112.245.103/Services/OfferService.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="OfferServiceSoap"
                contract="ServiceReferenceOffer.OfferServiceSoap" name="OfferServiceSoap" />
            <endpoint address="http://209.112.245.103/Services/OfferService.asmx"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="OfferServiceSoap12"
                contract="ServiceReferenceOffer.OfferServiceSoap" name="OfferServiceSoap12" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Check if the endpoint settings are on web.config. Also, try connecting with a different tool, such as SOAPUI.

Comment: I do have my endpoint settings in the web.config. And, correct me if I am wrong, but since I can ping http://[209.112.245.103]/Services/OfferService.asmx in a browser I don't think SoapUI can help me further...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configurations are correct. I just accessed your server and everything went fine (so it's not code related).

Since the site and the website are in the same server, you may need to use a different IP or address to access the wcf (try 127.0.0.1, localhost or an internal server ip).

Comment: I could also have modified the localhosts file to resolve the dns name to the the local ip...

Comment: Yes, adding the dns name to hosts is a good option since you can use the same config everywhere.