# Web config setting not overriding service endpoint?

Tags: .net, soap, web-config

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out what is going on here...

We have an application we are trying to deploy to a server, and we need to change the endpoint for a SOAP service that it consumes. When adding the service initially it created an entry in the web config file:

```
<endpoint address="http://subdomain.example.com/path/to/mapserver" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MapServerBinding" contract="ServiceReference1.MapServerPort" name="MapServerPort" />
```

We are attempting to change that to local address, to avoid it going out to the internet and back in when consuming the service (both for efficiency as well as firewall issues):

```
<endpoint address="http://serverAlias/path/to/mapserver" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MapServerBinding" contract="ServiceReference1.MapServerPort" name="MapServerPort" />
```

Changing this config value on the server does not result in a change of where it is looking, it still goes to subdomain.example.com.

Things I've tried:

- Create a console application that runs the relevant code bits, then changing its endpoint in the config file (works for that application as expected, and proves this server can connect to the SOAP service)
- IISReset (does not work, config's value still not honored)
- Changing other things in the web config to make sure that the config file is indeed being reloaded (every setting I change affects behavior properly, except the endpoint changes)
- Deploying same app to a comparable server (in DMZ, IIS 7.5) and changing the config for that instance ( *that* instance changes as expected )
- Changed the hosts file to redirect the call to subdomain.example.com to the internal IP (This works, but feels like a hacky way to solve it)
- Rebooted the server to see if that would clear any miraculous cache it had (did not change behavior)

Any ideas what may be causing the endpoint to stay at its initial configuration?

Here is a more complete excerpt of the config file (please note, we are able to change the endpoint address at will on other servers, it is just the production server that seems to ignore it). This was changed per Brian's suggestion of matching all binding names to be the same, originally the [binding name=""] and [endpoint bindingConfiguration=""] were both "MapServerBinding", otherwise it is the same as original configuration.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MapServerPort" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://serverAlias/path/to/mapserver"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MapServerPort"
        contract="ServiceReference1.MapServerPort" name="MapServerPort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Will try it when I get back into work tomorrow - posted the question right before leaving for the day. Thanks for the response, will check it out and report back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer to this question is *pay more attention to the stack trace, dummy*... I knew I had to be missing something simple somewhere, and it ends up I was focusing all of my efforts in the wrong place. I had been looking in the model, the only location in the code where the **service reference** I was trying to change lived... when there was another call in the controller to an **appsetting** config entry that I was totally missing.

The developer who created this code did something along the lines of the following:

**Controller**

```
FooClass foo = new FooClass( configFileEntry["serviceRestURL"] );
return View(Models.bar(foo.fooMethod()));
```

**Model**

```
using (BazServiceClient baz = new BazServiceClient("MapServerPort"))
{
  baz.GetSomeImportantInformation();
  //Do some more work here
}
```

So, we had two different endpoints that the server was talking to (one a REST-based API in the controller and one a SOAP-based one in the model). Since the REST-based API was hidden amongst other end-user-facing REST urls (these are web mapping layer services, so there are a handful of others just like it) I ended up focusing on the only one that (I thought) the server should be using for server to server communication.

Due to firewall restrictions on the REST URL being accessed from the server, the controller was raising the exception before the Model ever had the chance to execute, so my service reference edits were not reflected. This also helped explain why some of the instrumentation I added to ensure my config edits were being reflected never actually seemed to work. In case it ever helps somebody troubleshoot, I'll paste the troubleshooting code I was attempting to use below to verify that what the application's view of the service reference matched the web config's service reference.

```
        /*
         * This code is using (abusing?) the wonderful Elmah nuget package [ http://nuget.org/packages/elmah/ ] 
         * to surface the error in a way that is easy for me to find, so either install the package or swap it out
         * with your own way of surfacing the information.
         */
        System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ClientSection clientEndpoints = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client") as System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ClientSection;

        if (clientEndpoints != null)
        {
            //Loop through all the endpoints in the config to see what the config thinks it is set to
            foreach (System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ChannelEndpointElement endpoint in clientEndpoints.Endpoints)
            {
                string configFileMessage = "In Web config: [" + endpoint.Contract + "] points to [" + endpoint.Address.AbsoluteUri + "]";
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception(configFileMessage));
            }

            //Now see what the application is actually registering when it instantiates the service.
            //If all is well in the .NET world, this should match the web config entry!
            using (MapServerPortClient client = new MapServerPortClient("MapServerPort"))
            {
                string endPointMessage = "In application: " + client.Endpoint.Address.ToString();
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception(endPointMessage));
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("This is a bit embarrasing, but... I couldn't read the client endpoints at all.."));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This stuff is the worse. I feel your pain. Here is exactly what I have to actually get the service reference to respect the web.config settings on my production server:
(Also, just in case, make sure you aren't having firewall issues, consider using local ips or editing your hosts file if you are, see my question and answer here:

[Web Service Error "There was no endpoint listening at..." Firewall Concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641092/web-service-error-there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at-firewall-concern)
)

The following code will respect your production web.config, I would just use both the custom and basic bindings and not ask questions, I do not know if you need both but this is such a hair pulling scenario that I did not care:

vb.net

```
Dim offerService As ServiceReferenceOffer.OfferServiceSoapClient
 offerService = New ServiceReferenceOffer.OfferServiceSoapClient("OfferServiceSoap")
```

web.config

```
     <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="OfferServiceSoap" />
       </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
            <binding name="OfferServiceSoap12">
              <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
              <httpTransport />
            </binding>
     </customBinding>
        </bindings>
    <client>
     <endpoint address="http://serverAlias/path/to/mapserver/OfferService.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="OfferServiceSoap" contract="ServiceReferenceOffer.OfferServiceSoap" name="OfferServiceSoap" />
          <endpoint address="http://serverAlias/path/to/mapserver/OfferService.asmx" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="OfferServiceSoap12" contract="ServiceReferenceOffer.OfferServiceSoap" name="OfferServiceSoap12" />
        </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I added the custom binding, as suggested, and it still does not seem to honor the change in config. I also tried to change the endpoint address to use the IP, rather than the alias without any success. The frustrating thing is that the staging server lets me change the config back and forth without issue, it is only the production one that seems to ignore the web config.

Comment: Does your basicHttpBinding binding name match your new instance of the ServiceReference? As in   <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MyServiceRefBinding" />
       </basicHttpBinding>, than your c#/vb.net should be new MyServiceRef("MyServiceRefBinding")

Comment: The way ours is set up was <basicHttpBinding><binding name> matched the <endpoint>'s bindingConfiguration. The <endpoint>'s contract & name matched the code's call. (This config worked fine on our staging server to change the endpoint at will) I went ahead and made them all match just now, in case production was being more picky, and there is still no joy.

Comment: Damn!! Ok well there is a workaround, I know it sucks to do it like this but you can just declare the url when you instantiate the service reference, here is something I do localhost and dev: new ServiceReferenceOffer.OfferServiceSoapClient("OfferServiceSoap", GlobalFunctions.GetRootByName(WEBSITES.NAME) + "/Services/OfferService.asmx")